# PHP encode html for json_encode

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I am getting data of a WordPress post. In WordPress data is present in HTML format as it is tinymce edit field. In this field data is like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">

Caratteristiche principali:
<ul>
    <li>Sistema multimediale Toyota Touch� 2 with Go con display 8'' e telecamera posteriore</li>
    <li>Sedile guidatore con supporto lombare regolabile elettricamente</li>
    <li>Sedili anteriori riscaldabili</li>
    <li>Toyota Safety Sense</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have made an array with this field data and with few others.
Now I want to encode above content in a way I can get array data in JSON format using

> json_encode

function. When json_encode runs it does not return json because of above html data. Can you please propose me a solution how I can do this correctly. Next, I need to use this JSON data in python and to save in psql. I want to keep data in psql in html formate.

here what I am doing

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    $data_arr = Array
(
    'post_name' => 'toyota-c-hr-1-8-ibrida-122cv-cvt-business-24-mesi',
    'caratteristiche_tecniche' => '<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">

Caratteristiche principali:
<ul>
    <li>Sistema multimediale Toyota Touch® 2 with Go con display 8'' e telecamera posteriore</li>
    <li>Sedile guidatore con supporto lombare regolabile elettricamente</li>
    <li>Sedili anteriori riscaldabili</li>
    <li>Toyota Safety Sense
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Sistema Pre-Collisione</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Avviso superamento corsia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Abbaglianti automatici</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Riconoscimento segnaletica stradale</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Sistema Pre-Collisione con rilevamento pedoni</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Cruise Control adattivo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-list table-striped margin_zero">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Marca</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">TOYOTA</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Modello</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">C-HR</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Allestimento</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1.8H (122CV) E-CVT Business</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cilindrata Effettiva</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1798 Cm3</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cilindrata</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1798 L</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pacchetto (Tipo Eletta, Sport)</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1.8H (122CV) E-CVT Business</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Model Year</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">2017</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peso</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1455 Kg</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Portata</td>
<td><strong>405 Kg</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tipo Veicolo</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Manufacturer Vehicle</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Emissioni C02</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">86 G/Km</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Trazione</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Front</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-list table-striped margin_zero">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Consumo Combinato</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">3.8 Litri Per 100km</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Porte</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">5-Door</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Posti</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">5</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alimentazione</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Unleaded - Electric / </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cambio</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">AUT</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Potenza Massima KW</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">90 KW</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Potenza Massima CV</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">122 CV</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cavalli Fiscali</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">19</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Corpo Veicolo</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Sport Utility Vehicle</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Codice Ruote Anteriori</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">215/60 C17 96H</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Codice Ruote Posteriori</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">215/60 C17 96H</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>',
    'marca' => 'Toyota'
);

  echo json_encode($data_arr);
?>
```

To me it seam like problem is with econding of sepecial charcters inside of html.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with json encoding that HTML string. DO NOT alter data before putting it in a database, it should always be preserved as-is. If you are having trouble outputting the data then you need to apply escaping upon output which is respective of the output medium.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, when i try to encode this in json json_encode function, does not return anything. if I use htmlentities json_encode return empty string

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Please show your `json_encode()` code section.

Comment: Guess: the data is not *UTF-8 encoded*…?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus please see above I have added more details to my question.

Comment: @deceze I have used "utf8_encode" to encode the HTML string but i think it is not working correctly

Comment: Please see me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are manually storing the HTML inside of a PHP string you have to make sure that you are properly escaping the quotes inside of the string. `8''` is specifically your issue.

You should be seeing an error such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' e telecamera posteriore' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\path\to\file.php on line 150

If you are not seeing errors then check your error logs or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your file.

This error is telling you that in order to have single quotes inside of a single-quoted string you need to apply a backslash to create a literal single quote like this:

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    $data_arr = Array
(
    'post_name' => 'toyota-c-hr-1-8-ibrida-122cv-cvt-business-24-mesi',
    'caratteristiche_tecniche' => '<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">

Caratteristiche principali:
<ul>
    <li>Sistema multimediale Toyota Touch® 2 with Go con display 8\'\' e telecamera posteriore</li>
    <li>Sedile guidatore con supporto lombare regolabile elettricamente</li>
    <li>Sedili anteriori riscaldabili</li>
    <li>Toyota Safety Sense
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Sistema Pre-Collisione</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Avviso superamento corsia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Abbaglianti automatici</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Riconoscimento segnaletica stradale</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Sistema Pre-Collisione con rilevamento pedoni</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>?</td>
<td>Cruise Control adattivo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-list table-striped margin_zero">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Marca</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">TOYOTA</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Modello</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">C-HR</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Allestimento</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1.8H (122CV) E-CVT Business</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cilindrata Effettiva</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1798 Cm3</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cilindrata</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1798 L</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pacchetto (Tipo Eletta, Sport)</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1.8H (122CV) E-CVT Business</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Model Year</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">2017</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peso</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">1455 Kg</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Portata</td>
<td><strong>405 Kg</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tipo Veicolo</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Manufacturer Vehicle</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Emissioni C02</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">86 G/Km</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Trazione</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Front</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-list table-striped margin_zero">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Consumo Combinato</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">3.8 Litri Per 100km</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Porte</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">5-Door</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Posti</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">5</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alimentazione</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Unleaded - Electric / </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cambio</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">AUT</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Potenza Massima KW</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">90 KW</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Potenza Massima CV</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">122 CV</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cavalli Fiscali</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">19</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Corpo Veicolo</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">Sport Utility Vehicle</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Codice Ruote Anteriori</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">215/60 C17 96H</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Codice Ruote Posteriori</td>
<td><strong class="ng-binding">215/60 C17 96H</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>',
    'marca' => 'Toyota'
);

  echo json_encode($data_arr);
?>
```

[PHP docs: Single quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: "you need to apply a backslash to create a literal single quote like this". how can do this?. is there any PHP function?. I can not do this manually because HTML is being generated from tinymce editor in Wordpress

Comment: @ShahzadFarukh How does the HTML get from TinyMCE to PHP?

Comment: I am getting HTML from MySQL db using core PHP 5.6

Comment: I have used addslashes function to add backslash in html and now it works for me.  Thanks for your help and other guys help.

Comment: @ShahzadFarukh I'm glad you got it "working" but it sounds like you could be potentially tainting your data with whatever solution you found.

Answer (score -1):

Are you correctly escaping `"` and `'` in content you sent? I guess you are trying to convert given string that you input manually instead of getting that string in variable from somewhere else? This code:

```
<?php
$string = "<div class=\"col-sm-12 col-lg-6\">

Caratteristiche principali:
<ul>
    <li>Sistema multimediale Toyota Touch� 2 with Go con display 8'' e telecamera posteriore</li>
    <li>Sedile guidatore con supporto lombare regolabile elettricamente</li>
    <li>Sedili anteriori riscaldabili</li>
    <li>Toyota Safety Sense</li>
</ul>
</div>";
$array = array($string, "sample_value" => 2);
$data = json_encode($array);
print $data;
```

is working and results with

```
{"0":"<div class=\"col-sm-12 col-lg-6\">\r\n\r\nCaratteristiche principali:\r\n<ul>\r\n    <li>Sistema multimediale Toyota Touch\ufffd 2 with Go con display 8'' e telecamera posteriore<\/li>\r\n    <li>Sedile guidatore con supporto lombare regolabile elettricamente<\/li>\r\n    <li>Sedili anteriori riscaldabili<\/li>\r\n    <li>Toyota Safety Sense<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>\r\n<\/div>","sample_value":2}
```

If you still have problem, provide more detailed information about it.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. please check it.

Comment: Is there any way to insert "\" to special characters I think they are making the issue.

Comment: If you are receiving string that you are assigning to `caratteristiche_tecniche` in array from some external source like file or website, it will be automatically escaped. Problem with escaping strings appears only when you are putting this string manually in php script. So as you receive it somehow from Wordpress, it will be automaitcally escaped. Just save that string to some varialble and pass that varable to array and json_encode. @ShahzadFarukh